# For loop with array

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a next loop:

```
arrayI = new POJO_I [response.body().length];
arrayI = response.body();
arrayOfNamesMain = new String[10];

for(int t = 0; t< arrayI.length; t++) {
    if (arrayI[t].getMain().equals("1")) {
        arrayOfNamesMain[t] = arrayI[t].getName();
    }
}
```

After loop ending, I have `arrayOfNamesMain` with a few first empty elements, so actually it starts from the 5th index because first positions of `arrayI[t]` are not in if statement.

What should I do for filling my `arrayOfNamesMain` from 0 indexes? How can I sort the array and remove empty elements?

Comment: You're asking three different things in this question. I answered the one I think it's the post about, but please make sure to make clear, concise and single questions per post. Also your title's not very good.

Comment: Why are you initializing `arrayI` twice?

Comment: @TaslimOseni, no ideas :) fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill your arrayOfNamesMain using a different counter.

```
arrayI = new POJO_I [response.body().length];
int counter = 0;
arrayI = response.body();
arrayOfNamesMain = new String[10];

for(int t = 0; t< arrayI.length; t++) {
    if (arrayI[t].getMain().equals("1")) {
        arrayOfNamesMain[counter] = arrayI[t].getName();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayI = new POJO_I [response.body().length];
arrayI = response.body();
arrayOfNamesMain = new String[10];
int i = 0;
for(int t = 0; t< arrayI.length; t++) {
    if (arrayI[t].getMain().equals("1")) {
        arrayOfNamesMain[i] = arrayI[t].getName();
        i++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a different counter variable inside if block which starts from 0 and increment it inside if block if conditions satisfy... it will solve your problem.
int j = 0;
 arrayOfNamesMain[j] = arrayI[t].getName();